# Outlook sending "Not read" emails automatically in a batch

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013, smtp

A workmate's computer suddenly sent a whole bunch of emails with "Not read" receipts this morning - without the user being present.

The user is using Outlook 2013 and IMAP.   The receipts were all sent at 7:49am in the space of a few seconds, and the user was not at work.

I recovered one of these receipts from a receipient and there did not appear to be any malicious payload (I initially thought this was some kind of malware which got past our AV and filters).

Does anyone know why this would suddenly have started happening, and what the mechanism for it is?